# How to fill a dropdown in jquery datatable editable from the server

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jquery with datatable.editable plugin,
I'm managing to add a dropdown from static variables like this :

```
    "aoColumns" : [ 
            { // CLIENT
                type : 'select',
                data : string_in_json_format,
                submit : 'OK'
            }
```

but if i use the server side response, which sends back the same response it doens't work.
And i can't find anywhere what should be the format of my response.

this is what i want :

```
"aoColumns" : [ 
{ // CLIENT
            type : 'select',
            loadurl:  '/RetrieveDropdownServlet',
            loadtype: 'GET',
            submit : 'OK'
        }
```

The response of RetrieveDropdownServlet is exactly the same (as shown from firebug), but still the dropdown is empty
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found what was the problem

in my servlet i didn't add `response.setContentType("application/json");` so that was the problem.

Comment: Hi, I just stumbled across this solution and it seems to address my need, however I would like to ask a question. If my servlet/webservice requires a parameter, how do I pass the parameter pls. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, loadurl can contain a normal url ,you can add parameters to it.so yours would be: ` loadurl:  '/RetrieveDropdownServlet?param1=value1&param2=value2'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried it but it seems not to work, not because of the parameter, but the dropdownlist doesn't show at all. I am using datatables with jeditable like this   $('#editCustomerSiteTable').dataTable().makeEditable({
aoColumns: [{type : 'select',loadurl:  'addressTypesGetData.php?TypeID= ',loadtype: 'GET',submit : 'OK'},
                                {
                                    sName: "NamedOccupier"
                                }, .....

Comment: isn't the value of TypeID missing ? check on the server what are the parameters that you are receiving and the response

Comment: Hi, the value of TypeID should be null, how do I do that.Also the way I initialised the makeEditable, is it the right way to do it for aoColumns?

Comment: Hi, I got it working now. However, I have another question, how do I set the id of the select box so that I can know what exactly is selected.